# APIPA ip address in server 2003 dns for (same as parent folder record) can anyone suggest why this is?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, active-directory

have a server 2003 domain controller
i have installed active directory integrated dns

under the forward lookup zone for domain_name.local i see an APIPA ip address that is set for (same as parent folder) with ip number 169.x.x.x

looks like (same as parent folder) Host A 169.x.x.x (apipa subnet range)

problem is, from other forums that i have read, that this is due to dual nics and one on that is not getting a dynamic or static ip address BUT... I only have one nic in this server?

where could this be coming from and could it mess up other settings or not allowing the DC to be contacted? i am just wondering what symptoms could arise due to the record being there.

any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you have a NIC on the server that has (or maybe did have, this may not be something that is updated when you load AD/netlogon on a DC)?

If you have another DNS server in your environment you could 'try' creating a primary zone (not AD Integrated) and pointing a DC at it and restart the netlogon service. This should recreate the core AD zone and you can see if you have resolved the issue. Do this at your own risk! (see http://www.petri.co.il/troubleshooting_dcpromo_errors.htm)